# Android Toolbar Action button height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have `res/layout/toolbar.xml` which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    style="@style/ToolbarStyle">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is my usage of toolbar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />


    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I include it in any `Activity` Action buttons are shown and work as expected but there is one thing that action button pressed highlight does not fit toolbar [image]

Has anyone faced this kind of problem?

Thank you

Comment: are you using setActionbar(yourToolbar) ?

Comment: Yes, I am using setSupportActionBar(toolbar); in my Activity

Comment: So how is your Save button added to the Toolbar? You should really be using a menu item to show the Save button

Comment: Yeah I am using `Menu` and setting it `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be a comment, but I it is too long.

It is a **material spec**.

As you can see in the picture attached, the toolbar height is 64dp in tablet (56dp in smartphone), while the action button height is 48dp.

Also you can check the layout margin enabling in debug menu "show layout margin".

[image]

[Source:](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)

Here the specs for a smartphone:
[image]

If you check the style `Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton` you will find the minHeight and minWidth specs:

**values:**

```
 <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" parent="">
       <item name="android:minWidth">@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width_material</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/abc_action_button_min_height_material</item>
</style>

<dimen name="abc_action_button_min_height_material">48dp</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_action_button_min_width_material">48dp</dimen>
```

**values-v21:**

```
<style name="Widget.Material.ActionButton" parent="Widget.ActionButton">
     <item name="minWidth">@dimen/action_button_min_width_material</item>
     <item name="minHeight">@dimen/action_button_min_height_material</item>
</style>

<dimen name="action_button_min_width_material">48dp</dimen>
<dimen name="action_button_min_height_material">48dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Thank you, explanation is quite enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this will solve your problem but try replacing

```
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
```

with

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

in toolbar.xml. Again, not entirely sure it will work.

Comment: Might also be just "?android:attr/actionBarSize"