# How to set menu buttons height same as actionbar height?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

[Looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807309/android-toolbar-action-button-height) action bar has `56dp` height and menu buttons are only `48dp`. How can I set menu buttons height to be similar to action bar height?

Comment: Use '?attr/actionBarSize' as height attribute.

Comment: It looks like the answer to the question you referenced set the minimum size in dimen values. Have you tried changing those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `dimens.xml` following:

```
<dimen name="abc_action_button_min_height_material" tools:override="true">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</dimen>
<dimen name="abc_action_button_min_width_material" tools:override="true">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</dimen>
```